# I want to make TextField scrollable in both horizontal & vertical direction

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter

I want the ability to scroll multiline TextField in both horizontal or vertical direction. Currently, the Scrollable widget used by EditableText only allows scrolling in one direction i.e AxisDirection.down when multiline. My problem is it wraps overflowing text which is understandable but I want to scroll not wrap text.

I've tried [diagonal_scrollview](https://pub.dev/packages/diagonal_scrollview) but it doesn't work for TextField properly. Is there another way to achieve this effect?

My Screen layout looks like this:
[image: flutter_02]
The Layout is roughly like:
Scaffold -> *body:* NestedScrollView *body:* MyCustomTextField -> Column[ConstrainedBox -> ListView.builder, Expanded -> **EditableText**]

Comment: Share a code we can work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you limit the maximum width of `TextField` to some fairly large value, you can wrap all that with `SingleChildScrollView` with enabled horizontal scroll direction:

```dart
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: 1000),
            child: TextField(
              maxLines: null,
              // controller and etc.
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Another solution (based on [IntrinsicWidth](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html) widget):

```dart
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: IntrinsicWidth(
            stepWidth: 1000,
            child: TextField(
              maxLines: null,
              // controller and etc.
            ),
          ),
        )
```

`stepWidth: 1000` prevents `TextField` with empty content from collapsing.

However, there are some consequences when using the `IntrinsicWidth` widget:

> This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative
> layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where
> possible. In the worst case, this widget can result in a layout that
> is O(N²) in the depth of the tree.

Comment: It throws `Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 501 pos 14: 'position.minScrollExtent != null && position.pixels != null': is not true.`

Comment: Error happened because I didn't add `scrollDirection`. Thanks solved.

Comment: Is there any way that doesn't require the fixed width? It would be great if scrollbars appear automatically when the content doesn't fit in the widget size.

Comment: @shinichy try to use `IntrinsicWidth` (see updated answer).

Comment: @spatz Nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, for vertical scroll, I just wrapped the `TextField` with a `SingleChildScrollView` widget and set the `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical`. That does the work for me. However, I put `maxLines` of the text field to 6 because that fixed size suits my app's layout.