# flutter TextField maxLines and no wrap?

Tags: flutter

This is my code:

```
TextField(
  maxLines: 5,
  controller: controller,
)
```

I want TextFiled nowrap with maxLines, when maxLines was set, the content will be wrap, no horizontal scroll bar, is there any way like in html `textarea` bellow?

```
 <textarea wrap="off"></textarea>
```

- expect:

[image]

- current:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to make TextField scrollable in both horizontal & vertical direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044218/i-want-to-make-textfield-scrollable-in-both-horizontal-vertical-direction)

Comment: @Emre Sorry, it's been a while, but I have tested the code based on your previous answer again and it was successful.

Answer (score 1):

```
Container(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
child: TextField(
  controller: controller,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  expands: true,
  maxLines: null,
 )
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, when I type overflow a line, it still wrap, no horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SizedBox(

width: 230.0, //your desire width
child: TextField(
  controller: controller,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  expands: true,
  maxLines: null,
)
)
```

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: Check updated code: Wrap your textfield with `SizedBox()` and give it a width you'd like